# how to fix postcss vulnerability in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, postcss

Suddenly i got around 79 moderate vulnerabilities related to **postcss** package.
One of them is :

```
  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         postcss                                                       

  Patched in      >=8.2.10                                                      

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > postcss                  

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
```

I tired running `npm audit fix` but these require manual review.
Does anyone know how to fix these?

Comment: update `react-scripts` to latest version

Comment: will that effect other dependencies ?

Comment: As you can see, postcss is a dependency of resolve-url-loader which is a dependency of react-scripts

Comment: If react-scripts has updated the version of resolve-url-loader and resolve-url-loader has updated postcss to non vulnerable version, this warning should go away

Comment: also i am using latest version of react-scripts@4.0.3

Comment: in that case wait for maintainers of `react-scripts` or  `resolve-url-loader` to update their dependencies

Comment: Alternatively, you can use yarn audit instead and only ignore postcss package from the security check.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for react-scripts to update their dependencies or as an alternative use "resolutions" in your package.json to overrule the version:

```
"resolutions": {
    "postcss": "^8.2.10"
}
```