# Why cant I get the lastest version of postcss

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli, postcss, npm-audit

I'm using `vue-cli` which has the dependency of `postcss`.

When I run `npm audit` I get warnings that `postcss` has vulnerabilities and I have to upgrade to some newer version. How do I do this?

I tried `npm update`, `npm update -D`, `npm update -D --depth=99`.
But it doesn't work.

I also tried to remove `vue-cli`, which completely removes everything from `postcss` (I checked it). But then when I install `vue-cli` again, the old version of `postcss` gets installed again.

I also checked what version of `postcss` is required by `vue-cli`, and it only has requirements that say higher than version `^7.0.3` or something. But it should by default install the latest version right?

I don't understand why npm is installing an old version and I also don't know how I can update it to the latest version.

This is the warning that I get.

```
┌───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate................. │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                 
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package.................... │ postcss                                              
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in................ │ >=8.2.10                                             
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of....... │ @vue/cli-service                                     
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path.......................... │ @vue/cli-service > postcss-loader > postcss  
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info................. │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693                    
└───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Did you try `npm install postcss@latest`?

Comment: Thanks, that installed the latest version. But somehow I still get warning from npm audit. Why is that?

Comment: You didn't post the report. It should contain the explanation. *But it should by default install the latest version right* - the latest is 8, not to mention that there's NPM bug that would make `^7.0.3` install 7.0.3, and I'm not sure this has been fixed.

Comment: Please add the version of your vue cli package and of the cli service package!

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485205/how-to-fix-postcss-vulnerability-in-reactjs ?

Answer (score 0):

Refering to this
[how to fix postcss vulnerability in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485205/how-to-fix-postcss-vulnerability-in-reactjs)
there is mentioned that it is suggested to wait for maintainers to fix this issue. I'm also facing the same vulnerabilities with yarn audit...